# woocommerce cart is empty after adding products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce on wordpress. But have one problem with checkout page. I'm adding products to the cart, then it redirects to cart page(as I checked this option from Woocommerce Settings-> "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition"), in the cart page I have "Update Cart" and "Proceed to checkout" buttons, after clicking on both buttons I'm redirected to Empty Cart page.

I noticed a thing that cart is updated after some minutes and after that it works. What can cause this maybe cookie or session issue?

Comment: Can I see it on live ?

Comment: I am not able to make it work the way you are saying ...And one more thing I noticed that even if you just refresh the page after adding product to cart, it will show up empty cart .. So my guess is it is not product into the cart in actually.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I have changed my question did you see the detail that I mentioned?

Comment: Yes .. But if you check in network in `admin-ajax.php` after adding product to cart, you will notice that in reposnse it is giving you the empty cart ..
So product is not actually added to the cart. Reason could be(as you updated question), somewhere there must be timeout is set ..

Comment: What does it give you if you use default way to add products ? I mean without passing `?add-to-cart` parameter ..

Comment: I've tried in that way but no success, woocommerce verion is  2.1.12, can it be reason?

Comment: At last at which point is it working perfectly ? Do you added any plugin after that ?

Comment: No plugin is added. It's working after one minute staying at products page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72119/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-user3090189).

Comment: did you check your permalinks?

Answer (score 5):

The most simple solution:

Go to settings, change from "https" to "http", try it now, if it works there is a issue with woocommerce forcing autentication, you can simply leave it be, and use "Wp Force SSL" to keep runing the SSL certification and have no more problems with it.

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and tried a bunch of things:
  - installing a session plugin
  - updating woocommerce & theme
  - updating wordpress
  - updating my plesk server
  - adding session.autostart = 0 in PHP.ini
  - using expiresActive Off in .htaccess
  - removing AJAX on products and REST API in woocommerce settings
  - refreshing status in woocommerce system status

The one thing that finally worked for me (i think) was installing WP Force SSL

this sounds like an ad.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I did debug it and the issue was

```
woocommerce_sessions: Table does not exist
```

Deactivate and reactive the plugin, so that woocommerce plugin create a session table again.

Answer (score 0):

You are 18 versions behind. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/changelog/

Your WordPress version is also behind.
You should update both of them before continuing to try and figure out the problem.

As you can see by the change log link I posted there are a ton of fixes you are missing by not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

check the tick mark for **Force secure checkout** on woocommerce >>  setting >> checkout.

If you have https secure certificate it should ticked (marked).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, sometimes you add products to cart but the cart page stays empty (even if you can clearly see the cart widget has products). But don’t worry – it might just be a simple cache issue (and if you don’t know what cache is that’s no problem either).

Please follow this link for full detail: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-solving-cart-empty-issue/